# Search and get objects with Spring

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I configured ElasticSearch in my Spring (v.5.3) project and now I want to get result (list of all books) of this query:

```
GET books/_search
{
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": ["Author", "Blurb"], 
        "query": "harry"
      }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to search in multiple fields then you could use **`QueryBuilders#multiMatchQuery()`** where you specify all the fields to match:

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(multiMatchQuery("harry")
        .field("author")
        .field("blurb")
        .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10)
        .build();

SearchHits<Book> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Book.class);

return SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
```

Here we search the Author and Blurb fields for a match.

The first thing to do is to define a `Book entity:

```
@Document(indexName = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String author;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String blurb;

    // getter/setter ...
}
```

The second thing to do is to define a [customization repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) that describes the method you need:

```
interface BookCustomRepository {
    SearchPage<Book> findAllByAuthorAndBlurb(String query, Pageable pageable);
}
```

We then change the `BookRepository` to extend this new custom interface:

```
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, Long>, BookCustomRepository {}
```

Now, we now need to provide an implementation in a class named `BookCustomRepositoryImpl` (This must be named like the interface with implementation added!):

```
public class BookCustomRepositoryImpl implements BookCustomRepository {

        private final ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

        public BookCustomRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations {
            this.elasticsearchOperations = elasticsearchOperations;
        }

        @Override
        public SearchPage<Book> findAllByAuthorAndBlurb(String firstName, Pageable pageable) {

            NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(multiMatchQuery("harry")
                            .field("author")
                            .field("blurb")
                            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10))
                            .build();

            SearchHits<Book> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Book.class);

            return SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
        }
    }
```